# Quick Sort Sorts Descending Not Ascending

Tags: java, quicksort

I just implemented QuickSort algorithm from book and got weird output. It works but it sorts in descending order instead of ascending. For example: [1, 5, 2, 10, 6, 9, 8, 3, 7, 4]
is sorted [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] cant seem to find source in my code:

```
private void quicksort(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = partition(A, p, r);
        quicksort(A, p, q);
        quicksort(A, q + 1, r);
    }
}

private int partition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    int x = A[p]; // pivot
    int i = p;
    int j = r;
    while (true) {

        while (A[i] > x) {
            i++;
        }

        while (A[j] < x) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        } else {
            return j;
        }
    }
}
```

INITIAL CALL:

```
   quicksort(A, 0, A.length - 1);
```

how do i calculate the space complexity for the quicksort?

thank you guys

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in the same question. For your second question you should probably just Google it.

Comment: You should use a debugger to step through your program line by line, in order to determine where its behaviour diverges from what you expected.

Comment: O(N^2) is worst case. Average and Best are O(log N)

Comment: im sorry i thought that since its related to the same question i would ask here, i think i should modify my second question since its not the point of what is the space complexity the question should be how do i calculate the space complexity for it.

Comment: That is a much more involved question and should probably be included in a separate question (although it may fit better within a different Stack Exchange site.)

Comment: Space complexity of quick sort can range anywhere from O(log n) to O(n)

Comment: Actually you're both wrong. Best case is O(n x log n), average case is also O (n x log n) and worst case is O (n x n).

Comment: Space complexity of quicksort is O(n) cause its in place. Your talking about runtime complexity (which is O(n^2) and O(n log n) on average).

Comment: @NicoMayer You are not including stack space, which is the main point of quicksort's space complexity. Without taking that into acount, it's not O(n), but an exact zero -- nothing gets allocated from the heap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in your partition function, you are sorting in descending order.

```
 while(true) {
 //ignore all the numbers greater than X to left
 while (A[i] > x) {
        i++;
    }
 //ignore all numbers lesser than X to right
 while (A[j] < x) {
        j--;
 }

 //swap a number lesser than X on left with a number greater than X on right
    if (i < j) {
        int temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    } else {
        //Now the array is so sorted, that all numbers lesser than X are on right of it and greater than X are to left of it. Hence return position of X
        return j;
    }
 }
```

//for ascending:

```
 while(true) {

 while (A[i] < x) {
        i++;
 }

 while (A[j] > x) {
        j--;
 }

    if (i < j) {
        int temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    } else {
        return j;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i just changed A[i] < x and A[j] > x and it sorted ascending.

Comment: it works for the testing that i provided in my question but if i test on this input it goes to infinite loop: 
  int[] A = { 1, 5, 1, 2, 10, 6, 9, 8, 3, 7, 4 };

Comment: ah, was thinking about the same. wait i will update my answer

Comment: works! thanks alot, i modified so many things but never came to my mind to increment and decrement values of i and j there.

Answer (score 0):

The key point to note here is the part where you create the windows of all elements less than pivot and all elements greater than pivot during partitioning. Your implementation is making sure that at the end of the partitioning, left half of the array will have all elements greater than the pivot and right half will have all elements less than pivot. Just doing the reverse will make it in ascending order

```html
while (A[i] < x) {
    i++;
}

while (A[j] > x) {
    j--;
}
```